# Sitecore explorer, connect to project on an other machine

Tags: connection, sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I'm currently developing a new sitecore website.
There's my working project on my local machine and a project on a staging server. The staging server does not have Visual Studio.

I want to connect via Sitecore Explorer to the project on the server. But it seems like i can only give local folders when i try to create a new connection.

( The reason i want this is because there is some functionality that is available in sitecore explorer but not in the /myWebsite/sitecore interface.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean functionality available on server but not local? Is it a different code base? Or is it the data that is different? If the staging database is accessible from your local machine, you could change your connectionstrings to point to those database directly.

Comment: It didn't say that there is a difference between local and server but between sitecore rocks interface and the /website/sitecore interface

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the Rocks tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended that you use Sitecore Rocks in an environment other than development as it can open up some potential security issues.

However, there is a standalone version here that can be installed without VS.

http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/install/default.html

I would do what you need to do in Rocks then uninstall when done.

Comment: It seems like there's a lot less functionality in this stand alone version. for instance the only options under " tasks " is " set insert options ". I was hoping to be able to edit the presentation details

Comment: Yes, it's an older version. What do you need to do exactly that requires rocks?

Comment: The Windows version is the same as the VS plugin (currently 1.5). Make sure you are using the `Hard Rock Web Service` since the `Good Old Web Service` gives you a lot less functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the sitecore rocks configured in the staging environment (by copying it from dev, for example), you could connect, leaving the "Location" field empty.
Only operations requiring access to the folder would fail, but most of the functionality should work.